# Looking for name of sci-fi/horror movie about alien disguised as father

Tags: story-identification, movie, aliens

I need help identifying a movie. I watched this in the late 90s when I was a kid. It's probably a tv movie but it could be theatrical.

Here is all of what I remember about the second half of the movie:

1. There is an alien in disguise that has infiltrated a family of 4 or 5. It is pretending to be the father, while the real father is temporarily subdued.
2. The older daughter notices that dad (alien) is not wearing his wedding ring, which becomes the family's method of identifying their father.
3. Some time later, during the climax, real dad has returned (injured and with wedding ring) and they are trying to escape.
4. Alien dad shows up again and the two fight; real dad is injured and his wedding ring is stolen.
5. Alien dad reunites with family, with wedding ring on finger, and they think everything's cool, but real dad shows up just in time to kill the impostor.
6. Family looks at him like WTF and he reveals his earlier injury, proving that he is in fact real.

Does anyone recognize these details and happen to know the name of this movie?

Comment: see also https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/139827/a-novel-about-a-superhuman-government-assassin-clone-who-goes-rogue-and-tries-to (about the novel on which the film is based)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Everything seems to fit [Mr. Murder](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0140751/combined), but it's a clone, not an alien.

- It's a TV movie from 1998;
- During the movie, a clone infiltrates a family of 4 pretending to to be the dad while the real dad is temporarily absent;
- His older daughter notices that the clone's not wearing his wedding ring, which helps the family tell him apart from the real dad;
- During the climax, the real dad returns with his wedding ring and they try to escape;
- Real dad gets injured (shot in the arm) and the clone puts on a ring as well;
- Clone dad shows the family his wedding ring, but real dad shows up to confront him;
- Real dad reveals his injury (and his daughter's scarf on his arm) to prove his real identity.

The movie was based on a [Dean Koontz novel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mr._Murder) by the same name and starred Stephen Baldwin in the dual lead role, Julie Warner, Thomas Haden Church, James Coburn and a young Kaley Cuoco. You can see most of the details you mentioned in this (dubbed) clip:

Comment: Yes, that's it. Thank you so much. I would have sworn it was an alien though, but that's childhood memory for you. Now I just have to track this down so I can watch it again almost 20 years later. Thanks again.

Comment: @DBStanley No problem! :) The movie is... not great, but does have some camp value. Don't forget to click on the check mark next to the answer to resolve the question.